# How to split with Powershell with an XML string in it

Tags: powershell, split

I am trying to split data from a file using the first : colon. Which is not a problem except my file has a section with a data field that has xml data in it making the split not work on that line because it is trying to split each line that is part of the xml data.  How can I split that line so it keeps all the xml data in the Value object?

Sample data of mcData.txt

```
mcDatQFC:Service Disc Cache
mcConfigFolder:C:\Configs
mcDatQFC:Service Disc Cache2
mcDatQFCProv:Simple Service Registry
mcDatQFCProviderName:Simple Service Registry Name
queuethreadsxml:<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<mcQueueThreads
  xmlns='http://xxxx.org/mcQueueThreads.xsd'>
  <QUEUE_THREADS>
    <THREAD_ID>1</THREAD_ID>
    <ENVIRONMENT_INFO_INDEX>3</ENVIRONMENT_INFO_INDEX>
    <DESCRIPTION>GPC</DESCRIPTION>
    <CHANNEL>CM.D.2</CHANNEL>
    <HOST_NAME>myhostname.xxx-cert-ibm-mq.mydomain.com</HOST_NAME>
    <PORT_NUMBER>2</PORT_NUMBER>
  </QUEUE_THREADS>
</mcQueueThreads>
```

Here is my current code:

```
$mcContent = Get-Content "C:\Temp\mcData.txt"
$FinalMcObj = $mcContent | % {
$Delimited = $_ -split -split ':',2 

 [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = $Delimited[0]
    Value = $Delimited[1]
 }
}
return $FinalConsulObj
```

Answer (score 0):

- Line-by-line processing won't do in this case, given that XML value of the `queuethreadsxml` spans *multiple* lines.
- Therefore, use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content)'s `-Raw` switch to read the input file *as a whole*, as a *single, multiline string*.
- Using a *capture group* (`(...)`) as part of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) passed to the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator causes whatever it captures to be *included* in the array of output tokens.
- By making that capture group capture whatever the *value* of the `:`-separated name-value pair is (with that value possibly spanning multiple lines), *pairs* of the output tokens constitute the names and values, respectively.

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw C:\Temp\mcData.txt) -split ':(<[\s\S]+?\n</.+|.+)\r?\n' | 
  ForEach-Object -Begin { $i=0 } -Process { 
    if ($i++ % 2) { [pscustomobject] @{ Name=$prev; Value=$_ } } else { $prev=$_ } 
  }
```

Note:

- The regex assumes that a line that *starts with* `<` ends an XML document whose beginning was on a previous line, after the `:` following the field name.
- For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Kbp1mx/2) (the regex matches each field
  s `:`, along with its associated value).